# How to make CodeIgniter 4 date validation to enable users to submit only future dates?

Tags: php, validation, datetime, codeigniter-4

I'm struggling with my date form. This is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="date">Date</label>
       <input type="date" name="date">
       <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'date') : '' ?></span>
</div>
```

I'm sending date to my controller and I wanted to display an error if the input date is current or before the current date. Here is my controller:

```
$sysDate = date("Y/m/d");

$validation = $this->validate([
    'date' => [
         'rules' => 'required|greater_than[' . $sysDate . ']',
         'errors' => [
               'required' => 'Appointment Date is required',
               'greater_than' => 'Date should be in the future'
          ]
     ]
]);

        
if(!$validation){
    return view('dashboard/index', ['validation' => $this->validator]);
}
else{
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

After doing this, I'm getting an error even if I sent a date in the next days. Is there any solution for this or should I make a custom validation rule?

Comment: which error you get?

Comment: Well I wanna filter the date input. So if the date input is current or before current date then the error will pop out. But will echo 'Valid' if the date input is after the current date.

But even though I input a date after my current date, I also get the error 'Date should be in the future'. Therefore, I conclude that this ```greater_than[' . $sysDate . ']``` code is not working.

Comment: do an echo of your $_POST variables and see if the date parameter does have the right format.

Comment: I tried this:
 `$date = $this->request->getPost('date');
     echo $date;`
The results are in right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So last night, I dug up a lot and have found answers for my own questions. If you viewer are having the same problem as I then I guess my own answer here will help.

First I look out for `CodeIgniter\Validation\FormatRules` to look for the compiled validation rules. Then looking at the given rules, I understood that I wanted to make. Here I made a function inside the `FormatRules.php` instead of making other custom validation rules file and coded my own rule:

```
public function future_date(string $str = null): bool
{

    $curdate = date("Y/m/d");

    $date1 = date_create($curdate);
    $date2 = date_create($str);

    if($date1 < $date2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

Then in my controller, I made this validation line:
`'rules' => 'required|future_date'`